# Error: Activity class {com.example.thejourney/com.example.thejourney.WelcomeActivity} does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to test an Android app I'm working on, I can see the app on the emulator but I get an error whenever I try to install it on the phone.

I've already tried all the methods listed on other similar posts but the solutions don't seem to work on my situation.

A big part of me tells me the problem is there's repetition in the activity name as in Error: Activity class {**com.example.thejourney/**com.example.thejourney.WelcomeActivity} does not exist. instead of com.example.thejourney.WelcomeActivity. If that's the case, I don't know where it's coming from, I've checked.

Welcome Activity

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {
    public static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;
    LinearLayout l1,l2;
    ImageView logo;
    Animation uptodown,downtoup;
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
    l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l2);
    uptodown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.uptodown);
    downtoup = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.downtoup);
    l1.setAnimation(uptodown);
    l2.setAnimation(downtoup);
}}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thejourney">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" 
/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "A big part of me tells me the problem is there's repetition in the activity name" -- no, that is normal. You are seeing a fully-qualified `ComponentName`, which is a combination of an application ID and an identifier of the Java class within that app. Double-check and confirm that your `applicationId` in `app/build.gradle` is `com.example.thejourney`.

Comment: Thank you. After 4 hours being miserable debugging a problem that didn't exist. I finally realised it truly is my phone that's the problem. Despite clearing my cache, resetting app preferences, rebooting, disabling developer mode and searching the entire phone for traces of the old installation, it just can't install on my phone but it works on other people's phones. My wife has the same phone as me and it runs perfectly well.

Comment: @CommonsWare By the way, thank you for taking time out of your busy schedule to help others, I have subscribed, your book content seem like the ultimate Android Bible, just had to get it.

Comment: "it just can't install on my phone but it works on other people's phones. My wife has the same phone as me and it runs perfectly" -- that is very strange. I have never heard of that happening. You might want to post an answer to your own question, explaining that this was your resolution. "thank you for taking time out of your busy schedule to help others" -- you are welcome, and thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 0):

Your device might not work because developer mode and USB debugging might not be enabled. Try following the steps in https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#setting-up.